# .htaccess directory internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my localhost i use the php build in server, and want to block some directory.

```
<Directory /config/>
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

But on my debian apache2 server i ve get an internal server error. Apache2 error log:

```
[Tue Dec 21 08:38:31.577748 2021] [core:alert] [pid 30883] [client xxx:42012] /var/www/html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Comment: but how can i apply this on my example? did i have to chnage test into config?

Comment: Put it in correct config file, not in `.htaccess`

Comment: In an htaccess file you can not use `Directory` directive.

Answer (score -1):

Inside apache2.conf i use

```
<Directory /var/www/html/config/>
        Options +Indexes
        IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: You should ***not*** be doing this.  `/html/` is for serving public pages.  *If you have config, **do not** put it in a public directory.*